# Custom Shortcut Annotations for @Transactional not working

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to create custom annotations in order to shortcut, just as referenced in the documentation:

```
   @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Transactional("order")
   public @interface OrderTx {
   }
```

However when I annotate methods with the custom annotation, I get an exception:

> No hibernate session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation...

etc. While annotating the method with `@Transactional` works perfectly.

Since the method that I am annotating does not belong a Bean instantiated from the Application Context, my guess is that the `AnnotationTransactionAspect` is not working with custom Annotations, and AOP magic is not working.

How can I get custom annotations that shortcut transactions and work everywhere?

Am I missing something else?

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your appcontext.xml?

Comment: and also, what do you mean by "Since the method that I am annotating does not belong a Bean instantiated from the Application Context"?

Comment: and does the bean that is not instantiated by the context work with `@Transactional` ?

Comment: He means that he is using aspectj, not Spring AOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the pointcuts used in `AnnotationTransactionAspect`:

```
/**
 * Matches the execution of any public method in a type with the
 * Transactional annotation, or any subtype of a type with the
 * Transactional annotation.
 */
private pointcut executionOfAnyPublicMethodInAtTransactionalType() :
    execution(public * ((@Transactional *)+).*(..)) && @this(Transactional);

/**
 * Matches the execution of any method with the 
 * Transactional annotation.
 */
private pointcut executionOfTransactionalMethod() :
    execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Transactional);
```

I'd say it's pretty clear that meta-annotations aren't matched (and I don't even think there is a valid aspectj pointcut that could catch meta-annotations). So I guess you'll have to subclass `AbstractTransactionAspect` and provide your own implementation  for this pointcut to catch your custom annotation:

```
/**
 * Concrete subaspects must implement this pointcut, to identify
 * transactional methods. For each selected joinpoint, TransactionMetadata
 * will be retrieved using Spring's TransactionAttributeSource interface.
 */
protected abstract pointcut transactionalMethodExecution(Object txObject);
```

Comment: shortcut annotations in Spring 4 work fine, but they have nothing to do with Spring AOP. Or rather: since this question applied to spring 3.x, you should try it with spring 4.x. The annotation engine was rewritten in large parts for spring 4.

Comment: According to [this](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html) matching on meta-annotations is possible with AspectJ: `(@(@Inherited *) org.xyz..*)`

Comment: @whiskeysierra meta-annotations are about composition, not inheritance. The whole concept is not known outside of Spring